# [Yii][SQL] Do not getting records when join tables to get count of offers

Tags: activerecord, yii

I have following code to can sort by offers(bids and buys):

```
$clean_criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$clean_criteria->order = 'promoted DESC'; 

$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->order = 'promoted DESC';
$criteria->select = "*, (COUNT(aa.id) + COUNT(ab.id)) as offers";
$criteria->join = ' LEFT JOIN auction_bid aa ON (t.id = aa.auction)';
$criteria->join .= ' LEFT JOIN auction_buy ab ON (t.id = ab.auction)';
```

I am using pagination and sort:

```
$item_count = Auction::model()->count($clean_criteria);
$pages = new CPagination($item_count);
$pages->setPageSize(5);
$pages->applyLimit($clean_criteria); 

$sort = new CSort('Auction');
$sort->attributes = array('offers'=>array('asc'=>'offers', 'desc'=>'offers DESC'));
$sort->applyOrder($clean_criteria);
```

But to get offers i must use `$crtieria` when finding auctions:

```
$auctions = Auction::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

On site there is correct pages count, but on every there is one same auction. The problem is query return only one record, but how to fix this?

P.s Maybe i used wrong type of join and auctions which has not offers are not returned?

**EDIT:**

This code working properly:

```
$criteria->select = "*, COUNT(abid.id) AS offers1";
$criteria->join = ' LEFT JOIN auction_bid abid ON (t.id = abid.auction)';
$criteria->group = 't.id';
```

It returns `offers1 = 1` for first auction.

Following too :

```
$criteria->select = "*, COUNT(abuy.id) AS offers2";
$criteria->join = ' LEFT JOIN auction_buy abuy ON (t.id = abuy.auction)';
$criteria->group = 't.id';
```

It returns `offers2 = 4` for first auction

But when i combine it into one query:

```
$criteria->select = "*, COUNT(abid.id) AS offers1, COUNT(abuy.id) AS offers2";
$criteria->join = ' LEFT JOIN auction_bid abid ON (t.id = abid.auction)';
$criteria->join .= ' LEFT JOIN auction_buy abuy ON (t.id = abuy.auction)';
$criteria->group = 't.id';
```

It returns `offers1 = 4 and offers2 = 4` for first auction.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved:**

criteria:

```
$criteria->select = "*, (COUNT(DISTINCT abid.id) + COUNT(DISTINCT abuy.quantity)) AS `offers`";
$criteria->join = ' LEFT JOIN auction_bid abid ON (t.id = abid.auction)';
$criteria->join .= ' LEFT JOIN auction_buy abuy ON (t.id = abuy.auction)';
$criteria->group = 't.id';
```

sorting:

```
$sort = new CSort('Auction');
$sort->attributes = array('offers');
$sort->applyOrder($criteria);
```

pagination:

```
$item_count = Auction::model()->count($clean_criteria);
$pages = new CPagination($item_count);
$pages->applyLimit($criteria);
```

searching:

```
$auctions = Auction::model()->findAll($criteria);
```